# How to remove semi-duplicate directories in Bash?

Tags: bash, shell, directory, duplicates

How to delete folders that might-be semi duplicated?

E.g., there can be two versions `A` and `B` of each `folderName`. Either `A`, `B` or both `A` and `B`:

```
B_folderName1
A_folderName2
A_folderName3
B_folderName3
```

I want to choose preferred version `A` and delete `B`, or just keep `B` if `A` is not available. Following example above the expected output is:

```
B_folderName1
A_folderName2
A_folderName3
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Loop through `B_*`, and delete each of those for which a corresponding `A_*` exists.

```
for d in B_*/; do
  if [[ -e A_${d#B_} ]]; then
    echo rm -r "$d"
  fi
done
```

Drop `echo` if the output looks good.